# Creating a sub-directory on a network share mapped using symbolic link

Tags: c#, windows, subdirectory, symlink

We have 2 servers, let's call them Server1 & Server2. Server1 is our database server and Server2 is our application server running .NET 4.5 web app.

A folder on Server1 is created as:
C:\SomeFolder\SubFolder

The same has been shared and "Everyone" given "Full Access" to the folder, including for Sharing rights.

The same folder is mapped to Server2 as a symbolic link (https://superuser.com/a/244572):

```
mklink /d "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\App_Data\SubFolder" "\\Server1\SubFolder\"
```

Now I can browse:
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\App_Data\SubFolder

using File Explorer as usual. I can create files and sub-folders which appear on Server1 as expected.

However when I try to create a sub-directory using my C# web app:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\App_Data\SubFolder\Level1\Level2");
```

The same gives an error:

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\App_Data\SubFolder\Level1\Level2' is denied.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\App_Data\SubFolder\Level1\Level2' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
```

I have checked everything. I set the Application Pool Identity on Server2 to LocalSystem, got the same error. I set Application pool identity on Server2 to "administrator" account on Server 2, still get the same error.

However RDPing to Server2 using the same Administrator account and using File Explorer to create sub-directories and files work.

Can someone assist with how to get the sub-folder/file creation working by using C#/code?

Comment: Does level1 already exist when you try to create level2?

Comment: Where does this path `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Transportation\App_Data\Backups\2020\01\04\11` come from?

Comment: @Milney Nopes. But CreateDirectory publishes it can create nested sub-folders:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Please ignore. I updated the question. That path was the actual one from our system, while I used example directory paths in my question.

Comment: @Milney Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the correct one. I tried manually creating the directories in the tree at all levels (i.e. both Level1 and Level2) and it worked. Looks like .NET cannot figure out directory structure to create in such a scenario.

Comment: @ErykSun Like I mentioned, I tried the administrator account also which was working when using File Explorer. As a matter of fact, even after solving the problem using Milney's suggestion above, the folder wasn't accessible from C# using LocalSystem/NetworkService accounts but it worked when I set the app pool to Administrator account. For us, this is an acceptable scenario (off-course we will create another user and set the app pool to that user).

Comment: Not related, but keep in mind that symlinks are evaluated on the client and subject to its symlink policies for remote/local links and remote/local target filesystems. These are usually referred to as L2L, L2R, R2L, and R2R. Your case is L2R (local to remote). L2L and L2R are usually enabled, while R2L and R2R are usually disabled and thus fail with access denied. R2L is for a  remote symlink that targets a local path on the client (e.g. "\\server\share\symlink" -> "C:\Temp") and R2R is for a remote link that targets a remote path (e.g. "\\server1\share\symlink" -> "\\server2\share\file").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity:

It would be worth checking if the level1 folder already exists when you try to create level1\level2 folder. Although the documentation suggests it will create all paths to the bottom level, when working with network resources and junctions the API can be a little bit sketchy - try create first the level1 folder, then the level2 folder.

Comment: Change the wording from "junctions" to "symlinks". The problem, though it's not clear why, is probably because the symlink target is a UNC path. Junctions are mount points that get evaluated on the server, so they cannot target a remote path because the delegated access problem would be difficult to solve in general. Symlinks are used here because they're always evaluated on the client side. (Symlinks aren't always better. Sometimes a mount point is a better choice -- or the only choice, e.g. a remote-accessible link that targets a directory on a local drive -- not possible with a symlink.)